# Where to find sidebar menu Object Tools

Tags: interface, 3d-view, workflow

I'm following tutor4u's tutorial on blender and he does something under Object Tools, specifically under Object, join. I can't find that on my blender 2.76b.

Attached is a pic of mine and his sidebars.

[image: Pic of sidebar]

Comment: You need to be in "Edit" mode.

Comment: Try selecting some mesh first.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may have something selected that isn't a mesh. Try deselecting by pressing <kbd>A</kbd> until nothing is selected, then select the meshes you want to join.